# How to use preg_replace function for post_name in wordpress?

Tags: url, preg-replace

```
$post_name = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $post_title));
```

This code will give error when I put space or ) at the end of the post title.
How to fix this ?
What does it mean `'/[^a-z0-9]+/i'` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Lets start at the other end instead. What do you want to allow as title? Anything? Or are there any limits?

Comment: Here you can see the preg_replace in action http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fiJ (Push preg_replace button first). The function replaces all characters except a-z and 0-9 with '-'. I think it's the strtolower() that creates the error and not the preg_replace. As above just tell us what you want to happen and me or someone else will help you.

Comment: Earth is calling, please pick up.

Comment: Let say the post title as below

"This is my article (part 1) "

I want become this-is-my-article-part-1

So I want to remove () and space.

I want become this-is-my-article-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..
Try this:

```
$string = trim(strtolower("This is my article (part 1) "));
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "-", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/-$/", "", $string);
```

As I wrote in the comment, I believe the problem is the strtolower(), it tries to make "-" lowercase and it does not work.
So by first making the normal letters lowercase and then doing the pregreplace to make ) a -.
And then a second pregreplace to remove the last - if it's there.

The first two lines could probably be made to:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "-", trim(strtolower("This is my article (part 1) ")));
```

But I wanted to make it clear, each step of the code

Comment: $string = strtolower(" This is my article (part 1) ");

I want to remove - at the beginning

Comment: You mean the space at the begining becomes a "-"? Ok, try to use trim($string); before everything else.

Comment: @kostjakarta.com No problem. If it works then please accept the answer. If there is any othe problems I will try to help you.

Comment: the problem I am facing now, I can not find button to accept your answer. I have looked around :)